# Exchange 2013 PowerShell EMS not working

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2013, winrm

I get the following error when opening EMS on my local 2013 server (or remotely). EMS has worked fine up until recently and I'm not sure what caused the issue. I've read many articles and forum posts and none of the suggestions have worked.

Thanks,

Travis

Error:

```
 New-PSSession : [servername] Connecting to remote server servername failed with the
following error message : The WinRM client sent a request to an HTTP server and got a response saying the requested
HTTP URL was not available. This is usually returned by a HTTP server that does not support the WS-Management
protocol. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSSession -ConnectionURI "$connectionUri" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Excha ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
gTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : URLNotAvailable,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. A binding got wiped out on IIS. I don't know why it didn't occur to me, but our internal DNS scheme is different than our external. I had to re-add the binding for the internal servername.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been documented in this link
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/connecting-remote-server-failed
[image]
Try following the steps to run EMTshoote

Comment: Thanks for this. I was looking for this utility yesterday and somehow couldn't find it. Now, when I run it, it says that the user isnt PSremote enabled. This user has always been able to user PSRemote. All my other admins get the same message. Is there a way to check to see what users are remote PS enabled without running a script from a remote PS enabled account? Is there a way to turn it on for all users without being logged in as a remote PS enabled user?

Comment: Sorry,I don’t think that you could enable the PSremote without being logged in as a remote PS enabled user.

And you may need to re-enable the Psmore manully.

Comment: I re-enabled psremote through regular PS, just in case it was turned off but it was not. Do you have any thoughts on what would return this error if users really were still enabled?